# How to use shouldComponentUpdate() and componentWIllUpdate() method correctly in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Before i was using componentWillReceiveProps to update my component local object after getting data from redux.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.editUser && !nextProps.loading && !isEqual(this.state.user, nextProps.editUser)){
        this.setState({user:{
          name:nextProps.editUser.name,
          email:nextProps.editUser.email,
        }}, function(){
          this.setState({addModalUserEdit:true});
        });
    }
}
```

But now i want to use shouldComponentUpdate and componentWillUpdate as in react documentation as per react life cycle.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if (nextProps.editUser && !nextProps.loading && !isEqual(this.state.user, nextProps.editUser)){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (nextProps.editUser && !nextProps.loading && !isEqual(this.state.user, nextProps.editUser)){
        this.setState({user:{
          name:nextProps.editUser.name,
          email:nextProps.editUser.email,
        }}, function(){
          this.setState({addModalUserEdit:true});
        });
    }
}
```

but i generate an error as

> "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops."

Please guide me what i am doing wrong in understanding react life cycle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is your condition of `shouldComponentUpdate` is returning true every time.
Probably `nextProps.editUser` have more keys other then name and email. So it is not equal to `state.user` every time.

You can solve this issue by yourself. For that just add `console.log` before your if condition and you will get the difference between them in console tab of browser. Here you can compare and make a logic as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldComponentUpdate` is run before the update to the state (*and that is why it gives you the `nextState` as a property*) so when doing test against the `state` you need to use the `nextState`.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if (nextProps.editUser && !nextProps.loading && !isEqual(nextState.user, nextProps.editUser)){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Keep in mind though, that it is [advised](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) not to do deep equality checks in `shouldComponentUpdate` because it will hurt performance.

Additionally the `componentWillUpdate` is (*in recent versions*) being called [`UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate) and it states

> Note that you cannot call `this.setState()` here; nor should you do
>   anything else (e.g. dispatch a Redux action) that would trigger an
>   update to a React component before UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate()
>   returns.

---

The suggested method is to use the [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

Comment: i am using react 16.02 version and how can i prevent to update local state

Comment: what is nextState in these functions?

Comment: @hu7sy forget my last comment. It is not allowed to use `setState` in the `componentWillUpdate` as i mentioned in my answer. Can you tell me why the initial solution you had with `componentWillReceiveProps` is not sufficient any more ?

Comment: i don't say is not sufficient any more, i was curious to use react cycle as as shouldComponentUpdate is like flag to render new values come from redux and if yes then it will further goes to componentWillUpdate to render new values from redux

Comment: and what is the best approach not to re-render values all the time lets suppose i have value for user object which will be in redux state and i want to prevent to update local state all the time

Answer (score 0):

`shouldComponentUpdate()` is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received.

```
  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps) {
     return nextProps !== this.props
  }
```

`componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after update state.

Both method is not called for the initial render.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldComponentUpdate` use to decide that changes in props or the state have affected to component output or not.

`componentDidUpdate` will be triggered when there is an update on component output.

`shoudComponentUpdate` take 2 arguments, `nextProps` and `nextState`. that contains a new update of props and state. and returning a boolean.

[image]

Comment: what is the best approach not to re-render values all the time lets suppose i have value for user object which will be in redux state and i want to prevent to update local state all the time