# ShouldComponentUpdate getting called before I can set a state used in its argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext){
    return this.state.currentUser !== auth().currentUser;
}
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
    this.setState({currentUser: auth().currentUser});
}
```

shouldComponentUpdate is getting called multiple times before component did update can set a state. How can I make it set the state before it gets called again or is there a different way that I can make my component re-render on a auth() change?

Comment: try adding an if statement in shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802247/how-to-use-shouldcomponentupdate-and-componentwillupdate-method-correctly-in

Answer (score 0):

try to add an if statement in your componentDidUpdate method.

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  if(nextState.currentUser !== auth().currentUser){
     this.setState({currentUser: auth().currentUser});
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: this is the same as "return nextState.currentUser !== auth().currentUser" and always evaluates to false in my case. I am specifically trying to get it to update when the current user is changed

Comment: and you can possibly remove `shouldComponentUpdate` as i do not think its useful.

Comment: I changed the component controlling auth() from a child to a sibling component of the component I was trying to control and now have it updating when the props change. seems to work.